# Why "this" is pointing to something else in Javascript recursive function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following JavaScript code which has a recursive `boom` function

```
function foo() {
    this.arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    this.output = "";

    this.get_something = function(n, callback) {
        this.output += "(" + n + ")";
        $.get("...", function(result) {
                       // do something with 'result'
                       callback();
                     });
    };

    this.boom = function() {
        if (this.arr.length > 0) {
            this.get_something(this.arr.shift(), this.boom);
        }
    };

    this.boom();
    document.write("output = [" + this.output + "]");
}

var f = new foo();
```

When `get_something` is executed for the first time and `callback()` is called, `this.arr` is not available anymore (probably because `this` is pointing to something else now).

How would you solve this ?

Comment: this is the boom function now so it has no arr. you could assign a variable to arr so it can be accessed by boom

Comment: Is your question "why is this happening?" or "how do I workaround it?" Be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem is in Ajax requests and function call context

The problem you're having is function call context when `boom` gets called after you've received data from the server. Change your code to this and things should start working:

```
this.get_something = function(n, callback) {
    var context = this;
    this.output += "(" + n + ")";
    $.get("...", function(result) {
        // do something with 'result'
        callback.call(context);
    });
};
```

### Additional suggestion

I know that your array has only few items but this code of yours is probably just an example and in reality has many of them. The problem is that your recursion will be as deep as your array has elements. This may become a problem because browsers (or better said Javascript engines in them) have a safety check of recursion depth and you will get an exception when you hit the limit.

But you will also have to change your document write and put it in the boom function since these calls are now no more recursive (it they were at all in the first place).

```
this.boom = function() {
    if (this.arr.length > 0) {
        this.get_something(this.arr.shift(), this.boom);
    }
    else {
        document.write("output = [" + this.output + "]");
    }
};
```

### After some deeper observation

Your code actually doesn't execute in recursion unless you use synchronous Ajax requests which is by itself a *show stopper* and everyone would urge you to keep the async if at all possible. So basically my first solution with providing function call context would do the trick just fine.

If you're using async Ajax requests your `document.write` shouldn't display correct result, because it would be called too early. My last suggested `boom` function body would solve this issue as well.

Comment: Why not `window.setTimeout(..., 0)` ?

Comment: Why not invoking `jQuery.proxy()`, which whould be much cleaner.

Comment: @jAndy: He didn't provide jQuery version so I've written code that will work with whatever version he uses.

Comment: @Raynos: Of course. Could as well be 0. But I rather keep it as 1 just in case some browser (or future spec) would assume that 0 means *immediate execution*. Chances of this are pretty much 0 though. So 0 can just as well be used.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik please tell me that there are no browsers that execute `window.setTimeout` synchronously :(

Comment: @Raynos: **There are no browsers that execute `setTimeout` synchronously.** You can safely go back to bed... ;) :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

```
this.get_something(this.arr.shift(), this.boom.bind(this));
```

Now you've bound `this` to be `this`. The context inside the `boom` function will always be what you expect it to be.

`.bind` is not supported in non-modern browsers so use the [compatibility implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility).

As a side note `$.proxy` can do most of what `.bind` offers. So it may be simpler for you to use

```
this.get_something(this.arr.shift(), $.proxy(this.boom.bind, this));
```

`.bind` is [currently supported](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) by IE9, FF4 and Chrome.

[`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Comment: Non modern browsers as what? I know about FF4+ but what about others? And throw in jQuery version 1.4+ as well.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Just check the ES5 compat table. I've added it to the question. And if anyone still uses jQuery 1.3.2 they deserve everything they get.